# How to submit form data to an MVC controller with MailKit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, email

I've spent the past 2-3 weeks learning ASP.NET Core through the Microsoft Docs, Getting Started tutorials and a lot of stackoverflow searching. I can get by making simple web applications from the Tutorials but something that is beyond me is creating functions that do work for me and how to access variables from various parts of the application.

**My problem:**

Using MailKit (mail client library) with ASP.NET Core. As some may be aware they recently removed the `System.Net.Mail` from ASP.NET Core so I decided to use MailKit instead.

I would like some clarification on some of the questions I've displaed under each corresponding code snippet.

**My setup:**

- wwwroot
- Controllers

  - HomeController.cs
- Models

  - Mail.cs
- Views

  - Home

    - Index.cshtml
  - Shared

    - _Layout.cshtml

I didn't include every file in every folder. I only showed the ones I think are relevant for this question.

---

**View: *Index.cshtml***

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SubmitInput" method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" required />
    <input asp-for="Email" required />
    <input asp-for="CompanyName" required />
    <input asp-for="Website" required />
    <textarea asp-for="Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How do I send the information made from the `Index.cshtml` to my `SubmitInput` function within `HomeController.cs`

---

**Controller: *HomeController.cs***

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult SubmitInput()
        {
            string  fromEmail = Email,
                    fromName =  Name,
                    toEmail =   "user@domain.com",
                    subject =   "ASP.NET Core with MailKit"
                    content =   Message
                    site =      Website,
                    company =   CompanyName;

            // MailKit
            Models.Mail.Send(fromEmail, fromName, toEmail, subject, content);

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The `HomeController.cs` needs to obtain the variables from the form submission in the `Index.cshtml`. I just don't know why I'm not getting the values from the form.

---

**Model: *Mail.cs***

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Mail
    {
        public static string Send(
            string fromEmail,
            string fromName,
            string toEmail,
            string subject, 
            string content)
        {
            try
            {
                // Get, Set Variables
                MimeMessage Email = new MimeMessage();
                Email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(fromName, fromEmail));
                Email.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", toEmail));
                Email.Subject = subject;
                Email.Body = new TextPart("Plain") { Text = content };

                // SMTP Mail Client
                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    // Accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                    client.Connect(
                        "smtp.gmail.com", 
                        587,
                        MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTlsWhenAvailable);

                    // Since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                    client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                    // Only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                    client.Authenticate("user@gmail.com", "password");
                    client.Send(Email);
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                    return "Success";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "Failed";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where to put the MailKit code into. Is it allowed to exist in the `Model` folder as `Mail.cs`?

Comment: Are you asking how to get the values from the form or how to design the architecture of your system? How could the MailKit code *not be allowed to exist* in the Model folder?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with mail and everything to do with "how to submit form data to an MVC controller"

Answer (score 1):

> The HomeController.cs needs to obtain the variables from the form
>   submission in the Index.cshtml. I just don't know why I'm not getting
>   the values from the form.

`SubmitInput` action method does not have any parameter. How are you expecting the values from View to come to controller. 
If you have declared variables `Email`, `Message`,`Website` etc at controller level then that's not the way. 
In your case you should try to get the values from `Request.Form` as following.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult SubmitInput()
{
    string  fromEmail = Request.Form["Email"],
            fromName =  Request.Form["Name"],
            toEmail =   "user@domain.com",
            subject =   "ASP.NET Core with MailKit",
            content =   Request.Form["Message"],
            site =      Request.Form["Website"],
            company =   Request.Form["CompanyName"];

    // MailKit
    Models.Mail.Send(fromEmail, fromName, toEmail, subject, content);
    return View();
}
```

The better way to do this would be to create a model class with all these properties and submit the values as part of model class object instead of Form.Request.

> I'm not sure where to put the MailKit code into. Is it allowed to
>   exist in the Model folder as Mail.cs?

There is no harm doing that way but not recommended though. The proper way to do this would be to wrap email sending functionality in an service class.

```
public class EmailService
{
    public string SendEmail(string fromEmail,
        string fromName,
        string toEmail,
        string subject,
        string content)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get, Set Variables
            MimeMessage Email = new MimeMessage();
            Email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(fromName, fromEmail));
            Email.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", toEmail));
            Email.Subject = subject;
            Email.Body = new TextPart("Plain") { Text = content };

            // SMTP Mail Client
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                // Accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                client.Connect(
                    "smtp.gmail.com",
                    587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTlsWhenAvailable);

                // Since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
                client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");

                // Only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate("user@gmail.com", "password");
                client.Send(Email);
                client.Disconnect(true);
                return "Success";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

And use this in your controller as following.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private EmailService emailService;
    public HomeController()
    {
         this.emailService = new EmailService();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult SubmitInput()
    {
        string  fromEmail = Email,
                fromName =  Name,
                toEmail =   "user@domain.com",
                subject =   "ASP.NET Core with MailKit"
                content =   Message
                site =      Website,
                company =   CompanyName;

        var emailSentStatus = this.emailService.SendEmail(fromMail, fromName, toEmail, subject, content);

        if(emailSentStatus == "success")
        {
             //Logic of email sent successfully.
        }
        else
        {
             //Logic of email not sent successfully.
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

This further can be improved using Dependency Injection and IoC Container. For the sake of simplicity I have not included that in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

> The HomeController.cs needs to obtain the variables from the form
>   submission in the Index.cshtml. I just don't know why I'm not getting
>   the values from the form.

I don't remmember if it's still necessary to manually add the anti forgery key to the form like in asp.net mvc, but you could try adding `asp-antiforgery="true"` to your form tag to make sure it's sending the token.

By the way, doesn't your `SubmitInput` action should receive your model to get the information into the controller? How do you expect to pass the values then? 
You should either use a strong typed view or get the values from `Request.Form` dictionary.

> I'm not sure where to put the MailKit code into. Is it allowed to
>   exist in the Model folder as Mail.cs?

I recommend you to look into the rails file strucutre for inspiration. 
Normally what I end up doing is creating a `Helpers\Mailer` folder for this.